# ThreeJS human body painting

Tags: javascript, three.js

Having been misdiagnosed over the past 6 months, only to find a long overdue pneumothorax (lung-collapse) two weeks ago, I've decided to create a tool to help patients visually describe their pain-related symptoms.

The idea revolves around projecting the human body (only skin layer), and allowing the user to pain radiating/local/stabbing and etc. pain on top of this model.

I've researched the area a bit, but just can't get around theorizing how the user-panting should be facilitated.

My question is therefore, if I (as the user), wants to paint a red area WITHIN, say - the left thie, is the scene required to having rendered selectable objects (imagine 3d pixels) within said thie?

In other words, the user selects to draw, say - 50x50x50 "pixels" within the upper leg, whilst the leg being 100x140x250.

Am I going about this the right way? I've never been around webGL, but I consider myself very comfortable within javascript.

Btw, if any1 is interested in helping me in any way, you are more than welcome - I plan for the tool to be 100% free of use.